# How can I change the delivery settings of a google group member using api and .Net

Tags: .net, google-admin-sdk, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

How can I change the delivery settings of a google group member using the google api?

Within a google group using the User interface I can change the delivery settings of each member:
 - no email
 - Abridged
 - Digest
 - All email

I have found the admin API for both groups and members

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk

- /directory/v1/guides/manage-groups
- /directory/v1//guides/manage-group-members
- /directory/v1//reference/groups
- /directory/v1//reference/members

I also found the groupssettings api to change some more settings of a group

https://developers.google.com

- /admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started
- /api-client-library/dotnet/apis/groupssettings/v1

But I can not find a method to change the delivery settings of a member via the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't currently an API that can make this change. The existing APIs you mentioned are for manipulating groups within a Google Apps domain, and specifically for controlling the settings of the group, not it's users.

Comment: Is there any way to conceal the email address that appears in the "from" field of the emails?

Answer (score 0):

Commiserating. I wish to be able to set abridged delivery for members (and incoming members of my group too). To make sure I wasn't missing something, I placed a ticket with Google Apps for Education, and Google engineers admittedly don't have a solution (API or otherwise).

I've created a feature request on the Google for Work bulletin board. If you're a Google Apps Admin, you can log in and "vote-it-up" in importance.

Link for the feature request is here:
​https://connect.googleforwork.com/ideas/4623

Answer (score 0):

The admin SDK has been updated in the past few years, and you can now use

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members/{memberKey}
```

[cf. the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/get)